# Feature Request for Site Update: Push Notifications on Mac

Tags: feature-request

I have a (tiny) **feature request**:

Could you implement push notifications for things like comments, answers, reputation changes, etc. for Safari on Mac (and of course other systems if possible)?

[Tell me if I overlooked that feature, but I am pretty sure it does not exist.]

That would be great! :)

Comment: Hey! Did you get anything for this? It's a great question.

Comment: @penatheboss no luck apparently, ain't nobody caring, ha

Comment: Should we repost it?

Comment: @penatheboss I don't know if that's usually appreciated

Comment: Ok. Good idea though!